# SQL (Access), subquery: Find saleperson that exceeds $2000 in sales by month and what date in the month sales exceed $2000

Tags: sql, subquery, cumulative-sum

I'm having trouble creating a subquery in Access to cough up what I need:
Input: SalespersonID, Amount, Date

I need to find what SalespersonID exceeds $2000 in a month (easy) AND what day in that month the running sum of Amount for that month exceeded $2000 (argh!).

I can groupby and get the first month any salesperson sum Amount > $2000 but I just can't figure out how to get the first date in that month when the month running sum of Amount>$22000

Answer (score 0):

So you've got running-total in your tags - what did you try?

I would create a temporary table and generate the running total, and derive the month using the 'Month' function, and also derive the day of the month.  If you sort by month and day each month's data will give you a running total that is what you want.  This means you go month-by-month, and calculate the temp table for all salespersons.

It's not super elegant, but it'll give you what you want.